# Bash extended globbing bug?

Tags: bash, extglob

There are three files in a directory:

```
ab2 ab23 ab3
```

When I execute:

```
ls ab+(2|3)
```

It displays:

```
ab2 ab23 ab3
```

instead of `ab2` and `ab3` only.

Any ideas why it is like that? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug. `+(pattern)` matches one **or more** occurrences of the pattern. `+(2|3)` will match any combination and any number of `2`'s and `3`'s: `2`, `3`, `23`, `32`, `222`, `333`, `3223232323`—any of those.

If you want strict alternation without repeats, change `+` to `@`:

```
ab@(2|3)
```

(Or just use `ab[23]`. That doesn't even require `extglob`.)

Comment: So which pattern catch ab23 ?? try ls ab+(2). It will catch just ab2

Comment: `ab+(2)` will match `ab2`, `ab22`, `ab222`, etc.

Comment: "or more occurrences" that you are reffering to means that ab2222 also match the pattern.

Comment: @melpomene I know that ab[23] will do the trick but It's not the case. I wonder whether it is a bug.

Comment: @szawel What exactly do you think is a bug?

Comment: @John Kugelman It looks like it works like you described however it's quite strange for me. Thanks